# Quickest way to get results from multiple sql select statements?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Basically, I have an excel sheet with numerous select statements; wondering what's the quickest way to run all these and return the data to a file or query analyzer result window.

These are really simple select statements, they are basically

```
SELECT A, B, C FROM VIEW WHERE ID = '00001'
```

but there are about 200 hundred of these so I am wondering what's a fast way to run these

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to run them all in succession, and save the output, you can do something like this:

Copy them to a plain text file, call it my_queries.sql, then add a line at the top that says:

```
spool my_queries.lst
```

and then add a line to the end of the file:

```
spool off
```

Then you can connect via SQL*plus:

```
sqlplus username/password@your_connect_string
```

and then run the script with:

```
SQL> @my_queries.sql
```

You'll end up with all the results in the spool file, my_queries.lst.

Hope that helps.